# Show results mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i need show result in my database mongodb.

Im use mongodb.cloud atlas i already created database now i need show result in my database

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:test@cluster0.bvhvj.mongodb.net/*****? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
const collection = client.db("sample_restaurants");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  // need show result database in console.log

client.close();
});
```

Im expected result in sample_restaurants.restaurants in console.log

EDIT

Im use your answer but my problème return error

```
MongoError: no primary server available
```

this code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:test@cluster0.bvhvj.mongodb.net/****? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority";
client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
   const collection = client.db("sample_restaurants").
   collection("restaurants").find({}).toArray(function(err,result)
   {
       if(err) throw err;
       console.log(result)
   });
});
```

Comment: write query after database initialized, `collection.collection("restaurants").find({})`, why don't you google it before asking the question in SO. refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp) or [this](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://test:test@cluster0.bvhvj.mongodb.net/*****? 
             retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {    
const collection = client.db("sample_restaurants").                   
               collection("restaurants").find({}).toArray(function(err,result)                                                           
         {
           if(err) throw err;
           console.log(result)
         });
});
```

Comment: Your answer timeout in my console

Comment: For this error : 
   **MongoError: no primary server available**

Please whitelist your IP address by login into MongoDB atlas.
select "ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE" and click confirm.
And try to run the code again.

please refer to this video for reference (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leNNivaQbDY). @LamriDjamal

Answer (score 1):

First improve your code to fix the error:

```js
let db = await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true });
db = await db.db();
const collection = db.collection('sample_restaurants');
```

You have two different ways to get the data.

1- If your results are not a lot, you can get all of them in once and then print them.

```js
const results = await collection.find({}).toArray();
console.log(results)
```

2- If the number of the records is something like 2 million records, you can not use it this way. Have to create a cursor and then get them one by one.

```js
const cursor = collection.find();
while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
  const record = await cursor.next();
  console.log(record);
}
```

Comment: Im try your solution but my problème TypeError: collection.find is not a function

Comment: @LamriDjamal I update the answer. follow the steps.
MONGO_URI is the URL of your connection.